# Laravel phpunit Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: laravel, phpunit

при запуске phpunit тестов

./vendor/bin/phpunit -d display_errors=On -d memory_limit=-1 --log-junit junit.xml

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 4112519168) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /var/www/email_project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 332
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. in /var/www/email_project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:933
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/email_project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(773): Illuminate\Container\Container->notInstantiable('Illuminate\Cont...')

## 1 /var/www/email_project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(646): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\Cont...')

## 2 /var/www/email_project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(601): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate\Cont...', Array)

## 3 /var/www/email_project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\Cont...', Array)

## 4 /var/www/email_project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Found in /var/www/email_project/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 933

Comment: какой то запрос к базе сожрал слишком много

Comment: Действительно ))
Выделил из общей массы тестов те, на которых все повисало, причина в коде

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('queue_logs', [
            'hash' => md5($messageJson),
            'status' =>'test OK'
        ]);

тест ожидал несуществующую запись